# App Engine: URL Fetching and decompressing a large Gzipped XML file in Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gzip, gzipinputstream

I'm trying to retrieve a gzipped XML file from a URL. My problem is, when decompressing it using `GZipInputStream` in production, the content I get seems to be truncated. I can only read up to a relatively small part of the xml.

```
URL feedURL = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) feedURL.openConnection();
GZIPInputStream input = new GZIPInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
sb.append(line);
}
log.info(sb.toString());
```

This code always reads up to a small portion of the xml only. Running it multiple times displays the exact same result. I already tried downloading the binary content first by using a `ByteArrayOutputStream.` The size of the array is exactly the same as the file I downloaded. However, when I use `GZipInputStream` to decompress the byte array, I still get the same truncated string.

By the way, everything works fine in local so I'm led to believe the `GZipInputStream` is somehow limited in `GAE`. Does anyone have any idea how I might be able to go around this?

Comment: Have you tried to use URLFetch with disallowTruncate ?